# Fast method for hardcoding subtitles to MP4/MKV

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mkv

Until now I have tried 4-5 methods to hardcoding subtitles to mp4/mkv videos.

- `ffmpeg` - too slow
- `mkvmerge` - not sure thats hardcoding, because on TV subtitles are missing
- `mkvtoolnix` - program is crashing...
- `handbrake` - too slow

I'm looking for easy and fast method to hardcode subtitles. Lastly, if its important - subtitles are on cyrilic.

Comment: `ffmpeg` is almost certainly as fast as you'll get. Hardcoding subtitles requires a complete re-encoding of the video stream.

Comment: My suspicion is that it could be that rather than these applications being too slow the case may be that your computer could be underpowered. Video processing is usually hungry for RAM and CPU resources...

Comment: Try some online service like https://burn.monster .